# rails 5 route locale in mainapp and mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm build a rails 5 application and I configured the locale like so

```
# config/routes.rb
scope '/:locale' do
  resources :organizations, except: [:delete] do
    get 'settings'
    mount MyEngine::Engine => '/', as: :myengine
    end
    IchE2bR3::Engine.routes.draw do
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, MyEngine routes also have the scope for locale.

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  scope '/:locale' do
  end
end
```

Right now my URLs look like these

```
www.example.org
www.example.org/en/organizations/1/settings
www.example.org/en/organizations/1/en/myenginepath
```

As you can see in the third URL, en appears twice. Is there a way to mount engines and join/share the scope with the mainapp? Am I mounting the engine awkwardly/not in the right way?

Thanks for the help

Comment: How about you try something like this ? `MyEngine::Engine.routes.default_scope = { path: "(:locale)", locale: /en/ }`
`mount MyEngine::Engine => '/'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By using your suggestion I get a routing error: Uninitialized constant “Controller Name”. It seems it can't find any controller in the mounted engine